# Centering columns which are not multiple of 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The `offset` cannot be of any use for centering columns which aren't multiples of 2 such as `col-md-3`. But let's say one needs to have a single one of such columns that also has to be centered, how can it be properly done with causing minimum impact on the bootstrap behavior?

I found that by using margins the bootstrap behavior gets messed up. (a backend developer asking this question, I'm not a UI expert)

Comment: can you provide the code you intend to modify

Comment: @pTi: It's pretty straightforward, I wanna center "col-md-3" in a row

Comment: no code no chocolate, beside if bootstrap is not meant to do this , it won't :)

Comment: @GCyrillus: I assume you are aware that your comment is absolutely of no use and furthermore, I said bootstap, you want me to send the code for the col-md-3? isn't that so stupid?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 centercol" style="border:1px solid black;">
      This is in the middle.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centercol {
  margin:0 auto;
  float:none;
  }
```

See it in action: http://www.bootply.com/l7AArBXdlZ